# Validation for empty form action

Tags: javascript

How do I check if a form action is empty? At the moment I have:

```
if (!document.getElementByName('myform').action.equals('')) { ... }
```

which doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: If my form action is empty then I want to change it to have an action set to it

Comment: Try `if (!document.getElementsByName('myform')[0].action) ....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `getElementByName` method on the `document` object.

There is a `getElementsByName`, but you should be using `getElementById` (and the form should have an id and not a name - the name attribute (form *controls* aside) exists for historical reasons from the days before HTML standardised on `id` and `class` for identifying and grouping elements).

Once you get the action, it will be a string, which won't have an `equals` method. If you want to see if something is equal to an empty string, then use the strict equal operator.

```
document.getElementById('myform').action === ''
```

> If my form action is empty then I want to change it to have an action set to it

If the action is empty then it *already has an action set to it*. The HTML 5 specification makes it explicit that `action=""` or no `action` attribute at all should resolve to the current page.